# Why is my string capped at 32,758 characters when outputting to CSV?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, export-to-csv

I'm running a Python 2.7.12 program to process a lot of data and one of the strings I create stores a lot of data, but I have noticed that it is capped at 32,758 characters when I output the string as a CSV.

I'm running my script on a development server on an Ubuntu-16.04 VM with access to 20GB of RAM

Why is my one of my strings capped at 32,758? Is there a work around or way to fix this so that I am able to store more in my string?

```
import os
import pdfkit
import re
import requests
import urllib2
#pdfminer
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from cStringIO import StringIO

#Opening my files
#with open("GoodData.csv", 'w') as output: this does the same thing as what I have currently
output = open("GoodData.csv", 'w')
output.write("Company|Classification|ID Number|Incorporation State/Country|Address|Link to Metadata|Link to Data|Data" + '\n')

count = 0
counter = 0

archive = open("archive.txt", 'w')
qwerty = open("ProblemLinks.txt", 'r')


for item in qwerty:
#for item in linkList:
    print(" ")
    print("Number of documents parsed: " + str(count))

    #This loop is for testing, to go to a specific link
    if counter == 0:
        #So I get the links out of this
        meta = metaData(item)

        pdfkit.from_url(meta[0], 'out.pdf')

        file = "/home/project/out.pdf"
        holder = convert_pdf_to_txt(file)

        if holder == None:
            output.write(''.join(['|'.join([str(meta[3]), str(meta[1]), str(meta[2]), str(meta[4]), str(meta[5]), str(item).rstrip(), str(meta[0]), "No risk data found"]), '\n']))
        else:
            output.write(''.join(['|'.join([str(meta[3]), str(meta[1]), str(meta[2]), str(meta[4]), str(meta[5]), str(item).rstrip(), str(meta[0]), holder]), '\n']))
        count = count + 1

    else:
        counter = counter + 1
```

I am able to print `holder` before parsing is done and the entire document is stored there.

Comment: `output.write(...)`? Are your forgetting to `.flush` your file-object, or better yet, `.close()` it when you are done, *or perhaps best of all*, use a context manager to do that automatically for you?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've never head of a `.flush` and I have a context manager. I did not include a `.close()` because it needs to parse a couple thousand files before I need to close the CSV file it is writing to

Comment: Can you provide the actual code you are using to write to the file?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the last line in my description is the code I use to write to my file, I've started to think that it might be a limitation on `.join` which might convert the string to a 32 bit string

Comment: If you suspect the nested `''.join(['|'.join([...` calls, then assign their value(s) to a temp variable and check its `len()`. In fact, you could generate a test line of junk > 32,758 chars and verify it gets written out in full. But yeah, show us also your code for file opening, closing, flushing if any. Context handlers are a good idiom for doing that automatically and elegantly.

Comment: And also, which specific version `python -V`?

Comment: @smci I'm using python 2.7.12, and I've included a lot more code which should give more context, and I did the `len()` thing, the string length is consistently over 100,000 characters. I'm going to run more tests on `.join`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.

It has nothing to do with how I output the file, or anything with my code, its Excels fault

Apparently when I load the CSV file into an excel sheet it cuts the string into a 32 bit string.